# Windows console only showing the last part of a program's output

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-console

I'm having some trouble with the console output of my Java program. When executing a .jar file, the program has a lot of output. Actually it's not that long, but the Windows console shows only the last 30-50 lines. I need to get the entire output. Does anybody here know how to do so?

Comment: That would be the window buffer, try going into the command prompt properties and increasing that value. If that doesn't work, you can always try java -jar "jarfile" > output.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Solution

1. Select Console Menu by Clicking on the top left console icon.
2. Select Properties
3. Options -> Command History GroupBox
4. Set the BufferSize to 1000 or as request but less than 32766
5. Optionally Layout Tab & Increase Screen Buffer Size -> Height